# Microsoft TMG 2010 Sp1 override if authenticated?

Tags: content-filter, microsoft-ftmg

I have a TMG 2010 SP1 server running on Server 2008 R2 in a single-NIC configuration - not live yet.

I will be allowing web access in three fashions:

1. one method is using the TMG as the
   default gateway for our network so
   that devices that don't support
   proxy for web traffic can still
   access the web (albeit filtered
2. another is using the TMG as an
   anonymous proxy for a separate
   domain/guest computers that don't
   have accounts on our primary domain
3. the other method is to use the proxy
   server to get clients to
   authenticate to easily track which
   user went where.

Mgmt wants to allow employees to override access restrictions *if* they are authenticated (so we can track who went where) so that people can still perform their duties without IT intervening, but if they abuse it we can track it.

I've tried creating two Web Access rules within TMG: one that denies access but allows override for the appropriate AD group, another below that that denies and does not allow override for "All Users". The problem is that even if the user is authenticated, it matches the request to the non-override rule; as soon as I disable the rule, they can override.

Any ideas on how to allow override *only* if the user is authed?